# Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError: Javascript failed to execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, cancan, capybara-webkit, cancancan

I converted an app from Rails 3.2 to 4.2 that was using the `cancan` gem. Googling around and checking on their github says it's enought to just replace `gem cancan` with `gem cancancan` without changing anything. This doesn't seem to work. My test fails:

```
Failures:

  1) Redactable fields Manual redaction Redacting selected text in body
     Failure/Error:
           page.execute_script <<-EOS
             document.getElementById('notice_#{@name}').focus();
             document.getElementById('notice_#{@name}').select();
           EOS
     
     Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError:
       Javascript failed to execute
     # /Users/siaw23/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:305:in `check'
     # /Users/siaw23/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:211:in `command'
     # /Users/siaw23/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/browser.rb:232:in `execute_script'
     # /Users/siaw23/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/capybara-webkit-1.11.1/lib/capybara/webkit/driver.rb:80:in `execute_script'
     # /Users/siaw23/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:524:in `execute_script'
     # ./spec/support/page_objects/redactable_field_on_page.rb:15:in `select'
     # ./spec/support/page_objects/redactable_field_on_page.rb:22:in `select_and_redact'
     # ./spec/integration/redaction_spec.rb:37:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Redactable fields Manual redaction Restoring body from original
     Failure/Error: page.find("#notice_#{@name}").click
     
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "#notice_body"
     # /Users/siaw23/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:44:in `block in find'
     # /Users/siaw23/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:85:in `synchronize'
     # /Users/siaw23/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:33:in `find'
     # /Users/siaw23/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.9/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:699:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
     # ./spec/support/page_objects/redactable_field_on_page.rb:9:in `unredact'
     # ./spec/integration/redaction_spec.rb:46:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The elements being searched for can be reached manually after loggin in. This means neither `cancancan` nor `cancan` successfully applies `:admin` permission to my user that's created in the test. I used `You are not authorized to access this page.` and I get "You are not authorized to access this page."

The spec itself looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'support/notice_actions'

      #lots of irrelevant code

      private

      def visit_redact_notice
        user = create(:user, :admin)
        visit '/users/sign_in'
        fill_in "Email", with: user.email
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_on "Log in"

        notice = create(:dmca, :redactable)

        visit "/admin/notice/#{notice.id}/redact_notice"

        notice
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The `visit_redact_notice` method in the above spec is where everything is happening. I need help :). This is my repo if it might help: https://github.com/siaw23/lumendatabase

## ability.rb

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    return unless user

    if user.has_role?(Role.submitter)
      can :submit, Notice
    end

    if user.has_role?(Role.redactor)
      grant_admin_access
      grant_redact
    end

    if user.has_role?(Role.publisher)
      grant_admin_access
      grant_redact

      can :publish, Notice
    end

    if user.has_role?(Role.admin)
      grant_admin_access
      grant_redact

      can :edit, :all
      cannot :edit, [User, Role]

      can :publish, Notice
      can :rescind, Notice

      can :pdf_requests, :all
    end

    if user.has_role?(Role.super_admin)
      can :manage, :all
    end
    
    if user.has_role?(Role.researcher)
      can :read, Notice
    end
  end

  def grant_admin_access
    can :read, :all
    can :access, :rails_admin
    can :dashboard
    can :search, Entity
    can :access, :original_files
  end

  def grant_redact
    can :edit, Notice
    can :redact_notice, Notice
    can :redact_queue, Notice
  end
end
```

Comment: capybara-webkit 1.0.0 is 2.5 years old -- I would suggest updating it.

Comment: i updated `capybara-webki` to the latest version. looks like it's something else.

Comment: it's often helpful to throw in a `page.save_screenshot('whatever.png')` if you're not sure what's going on (and if you're driver supports it)

Comment: @MikeCampbell i did that Mike, i get the flash message that the user is not authorized to view the message. meaning `cancan` is not granting permission.

Comment: @siaw23 can you try: 1. allowing all roles to have access to the page and seeing if the test passes?  2. paste what your user factory does?  Is `:admin` actually assigning the admin role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple issues you might want to check out...

1. There's a new version of Devise out that allows authentication via feature / integration tests.  I've always spent hours debugging actually getting step-by-step login functionality to work.  With Devise 4.2, [logging in via integration tests](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#integration-tests) is now supported. You'll have to make some changes to the RSpec configuration for Devise, as noted in the documentation above for the `sign_in` method to work.
2. If at this point logging in as an admin still does not work, I would check to see if your RSpec configuration has `use_transactional_fixtures` set to `true`. If it does, I would strongly encourage you to let the [database_cleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner) gem manage your test database, and set `use_transactional_fixtures` to `false`.

One or both of those should get you around your authentication issue. My *guess* is that it's most likely an issue with the transactional fixtures, as Rails is likely cleaning up a transaction before you're fully authenticated (thus why I'd suspect #1 above won't work).